# flask relation returns query object instead of data

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, relationship

I have two models having one-to-many relationship between them

```
class User(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(40))
    posts = db.relationship(
        'Post',
        backref='user',
        lazy='dynamic'
    )

    def __init__(self, username):
        self.username = username

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<User {self.username}>'


class Post(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'posts'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(50))
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('users.id'))

    def __init__(self, title, user_id):
        self.title = title
        self.user_id = user_id

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<Post {self.title}>'
```

I have created sample records in both the tables
when I try to access user of the post it works fine

```
post.user
output : <User jon Dove>
```

But when I try to access posts of the user it return query object instead of data

```
user.posts
output : <sqlalchemy.orm.dynamic.AppenderBaseQuery object at 0x7f2fe1ad2c10>
```

then I need to do `.all()` on it to get actual data. This is how relations works (if yes then why `post.user` return data instead of query object) or I am doing something wrong here?

Comment: Yes, because you set `lazy=dynamic`

Comment: @roganjosh so `lazy=dynamic` works one way only?  as `post.user` return result directly not an query object